# Is there anyway to merge two gcov files into one

Tags: code-coverage, gcov

I am using gcov for coverage test in macosx platform. I finish the configuration for xcode by set:

```
1. Build Settings ==> Generate Test Coverage Files == Yes
2. Build Settings ==> Instrument Progaram Flow == Yes
3. Build Phases ==> Link Binary with library ==> add "libprofile_rt.dylib"
```

Then generate the files "`Test.d,  Test.dia,  Test.gcno,  Test.gcda, Test.o`" 
Then i use `gcov-4.2 -b Test.gcno` command to generate the `Test.m.gcov` file (this is what i want), but next time when i run test cases again, the files "`Test.d,  Test.dia,  Test.gcno,  Test.gcda, Test.o`" will be generated again, and the data will be reset.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there any way for me to make the data in these coverage files accumulated so that i can run so many times of my project and then generate files at the end.
2. If the #1 is hopeless, could you tell me how to `merge two Test.gcno` files (generated by two times' running) into one. I try gcov in terminal, below are the options for gcov command:

   ```
   gcov-4.2 -help
   Usage: gcov [OPTION]... SOURCEFILE

   Print code coverage information.

     -h, --help                      Print this help, then exit
     -v, --version                   Print version number, then exit
     -a, --all-blocks                Show information for every basic block
     -b, --branch-probabilities      Include branch probabilities in output
     -c, --branch-counts             Given counts of branches taken
                                       rather than percentages
     -n, --no-output                 Do not create an output file
     -l, --long-file-names           Use long output file names for included
                                       source files
     -f, --function-summaries        Output summaries for each function
     -o, --object-directory DIR|FILE Search for object files in DIR or called FILE
     -p, --preserve-paths            Preserve all pathname components
     -u, --unconditional-branches    Show unconditional branch counts too

   For bug reporting instructions, please see:
   <URL:http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter>.
   ```

Thanks for all your help in advance

Answer (score 22):

The usual workflow for `gcov` is

1. Compile and link with coverage support (`-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`)
2. Run your executables, possibly multiple times, possibly with different parameters / settings. This will create accumulative usage information in the `.gcda` files
3. Invoke `gcov` to get coverage statistics in a human-readable format (`.gcov`)

So basically, successive runs of the application will result in accumulated coverage statistics. It's just that these accumulations will take place in the `.gcda` files, not the `.gcov` files, so you have to re-run `gcov` each time you want to see updated statistics.

Comment: What if multiple tests were executed in several docker containers? Is there any way to get the combined and distinct coverage report?

Comment: Do you find any way to get the combined coverage report for execution in several docker containers?